# Searching _source and returning only needed fields using Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using Java to perform queries on Elasticsearch, via the ElasticSearchClient. As there are big variables returned, I would like to only retrieve the ones that are relevant but the variables in _source are nested.

Below is a sample index response (multiple indexes can be returned with same _source structure)

```json
[
    {
        "_index": "kn-tas-20200630",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1122334455",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
            "variables": [
                {
                    "rawValue": "DEFH",
                    "name": "MANAGER"
                },
                {
                    "rawValue": "ABCD",
                    "name": "EMPLOYEE"
                },
                {
                    "rawValue": "[{\"rowId\":102030,\"rowType\":\"SIM\"}]",
                    "name": "extData"
                }
            ]
        },
        "sort": [
            1665735632119
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to create a query using SearchSourceBuilder to query ES and only retrieve the following:

- Get the rawValue by name (I provide Manager, I get "DFEH")
- Get the rowType value (I provide extData + row Type, I get "SIM")

Below is my query:

```json
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 100,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "prcKey": [
                            "K-112"
                        ],
                        "boost": 1.0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "endDate",
                        "boost": 1.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "personInCharge": {
                            "value": "ABC",
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    },
    "_source": {
        "includes": [
            "variables.name",
            "variables.rawValue"
        ],
        "excludes": []
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "createTime": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I fix my query? I tried using nested queries but without any luck.

Comment: Hi, I am assuming that your query does not work, but could you explain what is failing explicitly.

Comment: what is data type of `variables` field ? is it nested or object? can you please post your index mapping ?